# Bootstrap 3 dynamic carousel doesnt slide

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please help. when i use the default carousel,

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="..." alt="...">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
...
```

slide does work, but when i while looped the
 `<div class="item active">...</div>` so the images will be dynamic, it doesnt slide anymore. instead, the images just stacked each other as seen here: 
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0T65.jpg)
Here is my code:

```
          <!-- carousel -->
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php 
        $x = new DB();
        $y= $x->selectWithCount(0,'tblimagecarousel',null,null);
        // var_dump($y);
        $numofimages = $y->fetchColumn();
        // echo $numofimages;
        for($x=0;$x<$numofimages;$x++)
        {
          echo "<li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='{$x}'></li>";
        }
       ?>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php 
      $x = new DB();
      $y= $x->select(0,'*','tblimagecarousel',null,null);

      while($row = $y->fetchObject()){
        echo"
        <div class='item active'>
        <img src='../assets/images/".$row->img."' alt='".$row->title."' width='100%' height='345'>
        <div class='carousel-caption'>
          <h3>".$row->title."</h3> 
          <p>".$row->description."</p>
        </div>
        </div>";

      }
    ?>
    </div>
    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev" >
      <span><img src="../assets/images/ico_prev.png" height="50px" style="margin-top:500%"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span><img src="../assets/images/ico_next.png" height="50px" style="margin-top:500%"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: paste your rendered HTML maybe we can help see what has happened

Comment: io think i see the issue (i have not tested it ) but the active class cannot be applied to all your DIVs remove that and see if that helps. after you generate them all add the active class to one of them and you may have to call the $('.carousel').carousel() function

Comment: after further exam of your code.... you may want to only make the db call once and fetch all into an array then you will have all the info you need in one place. does your db call fetch the intended results?

Comment: Yes i have no problem in db call fetch as i get the my expected images result. So you think the problem is is the active in data-target li?

Comment: What happens if you remove the active class from the loop. And maybe add it to only the last item?

Comment: no image will display

Comment: You have to make only one of them with the "active" class. what code changes have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your code your issue is in your loop

the carousel can only have ONE item with the active class at a time (if you only want one to show)

this does not contain the php portion you will have to construct your loop to NOT add the active class (possibly add the active class to the 1st item after)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../assets/images/image1.png" alt="Image one" width="100%" height="345">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Image one</h3>
        <p>Image Description 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../assets/images/image2.png" alt="Image two" width="100%" height="345">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Image two</h3>
        <p>Image Description 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../assets/images/image3.png" alt="Image three" width="100%" height="345">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Image three</h3>
        <p>Image Description 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="../assets/images/image4.png" alt="Image four" width="100%" height="345">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Image four</h3>
        <p>Image Description 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span><img src="../assets/images/ico_prev.png" height="50px" ></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span><img src="../assets/images/ico_next.png" height="50px" ></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    body{background-color:#ccc;}
.item{height:400px;}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myCarousel').carousel();
 //this will add the active class to the first item
  $('.carousel-inner div.item:first-of-type' ).addClass( "active" );
})
```

You can view a fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/happymacarts/ntexh6Lb/5/)